# Assembly embedded resources

Tags: asp.net, .net, assemblies, scriptcontrol

Does the row below is required in AssemblyInfo.cs if i want to add an embedded script to the assembly with my custom usercontrol? Does exists any alternative to this?

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Modal.js", "text/javascript")]
```

I'm developing custom IScriptControl that has JS. Both, CS and JS of the control are in same assembly. In the control, i have a lines:

```
ScriptReference reference = new ScriptReference();
reference.Assembly = "Modal";
reference.Name = "Modal.js";
```

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: Many developers will add the controls to that library, and I would like to make their life easier...not edit AssemblyInfo for each new control. Another thing that in my mind, is ability to make that script source dynamic (configured with property, or embedded by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Modal.js", "text/javascript")]
```

can be written or in AssemblyInfo.cs or above of namespace

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Modal.js", "text/javascript")]
namespace Core.Web.UI.ScriptControls
{
```

Now it easier for developers to add new controls.

Answer (score -1):

You could embed the script into the assembly containing the control which the developers will use without the need to declare it in their own assembly. Microsoft did the same thing with the System.Web assembly containing their base controls, so all that a developer needs is reference this assembly. and place the control onto the WebForm.

Comment: I know it and I'm looking for a way just to not modify AssemblyInfo file for each control that I add to my library

Comment: In this case you will have to find another way to reference your javascript files.